# Castle.Windsor lifestyles in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, castle-windsor

In my current WebAPi project, I use UnitOfWork and Repository patterns. My current DI code is the following:

```
public class DependencyInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
                    //log4net
                    Component.For<ILogService>()
                        .ImplementedBy<LogService>()
                        .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,

                    Component.For(typeof(IDatabaseFactory<>))
                        .ImplementedBy(typeof(DatabaseFactory<>))
                        .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

                    Component.For(typeof(IUnitOfWork<>))
                        .ImplementedBy(typeof(UnitOfWork<>))
                        .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

                    Types.FromThisAssembly()
                        .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
                        .LifestyleTransient(),

                    //unit of work and repositories here
                    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyServer.DAL")
                        .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                        .LifestylePerWebRequest(),

                    //service layer
                    Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyServer.Service")
                        .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
                        .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                    );
    }

}
```

The client is a WinForms app, and each client can connect to a different database (having the same model)

All the above are set to per webrequest lifestyle. My main concern is that the database connection is created/open for every request, so I can't share the context/uow between the controller's actions.

Furthermore, I need to reference the EntityFramework package in my WebAPI package even though I'm not using it myself. However, the DI needs it.

Is this necessary or can I change lifestyles of certain classes?

Comment: Is what necessary? PerWebRequest lifestyle makes no sense in a WinForms app.

Comment: For the 'connections' : Even if you close a connection after web request it is saved in the .net connection pool and not disposed off completely. To understand it properly read all [here ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .